# Rails 4 How to load a has_many association to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller called Edit an existing client which does what the name implies. It will load up a client of that name and pull all relevant information if it exists. In the view I have

```
@client = Client.find_by(:id => 1)
```

and it loads all the information up correctly for anything that has_one association to Client. However for something like address which a Client has_many of, it does not show at all in the view. How would I fix this?

Example [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ610.png)

The address stuff should show up under number of dependents but it does not.

This is the [view](http://pastebin.com/ZDCYZHwq)

And [here](http://pastebin.com/2FL4if5f) is the table for addresses

[Here](http://pastebin.com/uN5Mnbs3) is the controller for client

[Here](http://pastebin.com/uN5Mnbs3) are the models

**UPDATE** Thank you bntzio. I am actually dumb. It is now pulling the types of addresses as it should, however the form allows you to add a former address and a mailing address. This is handled by a series of bools in the table. Right now it just pulls all three addresses and puts them under "Present Address". How would I add logic to pull the correct address for that section?

Sample output [here](http://puu.sh/kcPcW/7f575270de.png)

Comment: Did you implement the logic to display the `address`? Paste your view code in the question.

Comment: Please add the view logic in your question and I am assuming that models relation are set up properly.

Comment: Yeah that's the part I need help with. I'm completely new to all of this. I have no idea what I would write there. Would I create a new variable and find_by the type of address then load it?

Comment: The Question is unclear, I would suggest to put the `models` with clear `relationship`, `controller action` and `corresponding view` code in the question

Comment: I agree with @illusionist

Comment: Can u please check if your :address_and_infos variable have a value? Because if it doesn't, that's the problem, it cannot render because it has nothing to render. @user3650416

Comment: Thanks a ton for that @bntzio ._.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider here, the first one:

- You should have a column for address in your database. Check your db migrations.

It should look like this:

```
t.string :address
```

If you don't have that table in your db, then you can't access that variable holding the address, so you need to add it with a migration.

`rails g migration AddAddressToUsers address:string` 
or

`rails g migration AddAddressToClients address:string` (depending on how you have it).

Then do a migration to migrate the changes:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Reload your server and add the proper code in the view and it should be displayed correctly.

The second thing is:

- Check your controller if it contains strong parameters, if yes, then add your :address variable (anyway you need to have that variable in your db, as mentioned before).